# Yield/iterator corner cases

Tags: c#

On this article ( http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/13/8854601.aspx), there is a pop question about iterators and one concerning a corner case:

> Exercise: Consider the following
>   fragment:   foreach (int i in
>   CountTo100Twice()) {   ...  }
>
> Explain what happens on the 150th call
>   to MoveNext() in the above loop.
>   Discuss its consequences for recursive
>   enumerators (such as tree traversal).

I haven't run this code, but I am assuming that this is a question supposedly with an answer from the articles (all links provided below), but I can't find the answer in the knowledge shared by the article or in the comments for this particular article.

Does anyone know what the answer is? What other corner cases are there?

1) http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/12/8849519.aspx

2) http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/13/8854601.aspx

3) http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/14/8862242.aspx

4) http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/15/8868267.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate what the actual question is?

Comment: The question is: Explain what happens on the 150th call to MoveNext() in the above loop. Discuss its consequences for recursive enumerators (such as tree traversal).

Comment: I have posted a series of blog articles on iterator corner cases. (Thanks for the idea!) http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Iterators/default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect he *may* be referring to the fact that each call to `MoveNext()` invokes a state machine which in turn invokes `MoveNext()` on another state machine, making it all a bit inefficient.

This is blogged about [here by Wes Dyer](http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx) and [here by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/19/immutability-in-c-part-seven-more-on-binary-trees.aspx).

The main corner case I'd say with iterator blocks is that *nothing* is executed before the first call to `MoveNext()`. So this method:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string file)
{
    if (file == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("file");
    }
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }        
}
```

doesn't actually throw the exception until you start iterating. Instead, you need to write something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string file)
{
    if (file == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("file");
    }
    return ReadLinesImpl(file);
}

public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLinesImpl(string file)
{
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }        
}
```

Again, Eric has blogged on this: [part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/05/psychic-debugging-part-one.aspx), [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/06/psychic-debugging-part-two.aspx). I've blogged a [suggestion to make life easier](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/03/02/c-4-idea-iterator-blocks-and-parameter-checking/) too, although I doubt it'll ever come to anything.

Comment: The fact is that recursive iterators are like recursive function calls : They are prone to stack overflow problems. And they are even more inneficient as they create/free lots of temporary objects (Each iterator being one).

Tree traversal is one of the case where such performance problems are easy to see. A dumb tree traversal using recursive iterators will create one temporary iterator object per node...

Comment: Jon, I thought you had to yield in the 'top level' function? See Raymond's post... "As state machines, all yield return statements must occur at the top level."

Comment: dss539: Raymond post is exact, but returning IEnumerable doesn't transform your function into a state machine. That's why Jon's code work : "ReadLine" is just a standard function. The limitation come when you want to call a function to do the yield for you while you are inside a function already doing some yield... it can't work.

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

(1) Jon is of course correct; the issue is that nesting iterators like this gives you a call stack of iterator logic. If you are iterating a deep recursively defined data structure, this can blow the stack, and there are easy ways to turn what ought to be a linear algorithm into a quadratic algorithm.  See Wes's article for more details.

(2) We could build a new kind of iterator logic into the language that did not have the performance problem. I would love to implement this but it is not a high enough priority right now. If you're interested in the technical details of how to do so, read [this paper](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/cache/papers/cs2/355/http:zSzzSzwww.cs.kuleuven.ac.bezSz~frankzSzPAPERSzSzFTfJP2005.pdf/iterators-revisited-proof-rules.pdf).

(3) There are many corner cases; the ones already alluded to (deferred execution of bounds checks and deferred execution of finally blocks) are the two most common. Unfortunately, in many versions of C# there are bugs in the code generator that exacerbate the latter problem. Suppose you have try { try { ... yield ... } finally { X() } } finally { Y() } -- there are weird situations you can get into where the code we generate accidentally calls Y() before X() on the cleanup path, which is clearly wrong. We've fixed those for the service pack, but if you find others, please let me know.

(4) There are also some extant extremely obscure bugs involving the exact behaviour of the iterator when doing crazy things like a yield break out of a finally which then branches to an outer finally which does a second, redundant yield break. Again, if you happen to find bizarre-behaving iterators, feel free to bring them to my attention.

Comment: So far when my iterators have behaved bizarrely it's been entirely due to my code being bizarre ;)

Answer (score 1):

One interesting corner case with yield/iterators happens when you consider `try..finally` and the derivative `using` and `lock` statements.  Consider the iterator block Jon Skeet posted above:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string file)
{
    if (file == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("file");
    }
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }        
}
```

If you use this iterator block outside of the context of a `foreach` by calling `MoveNext()` manually a couple of times and you **never** finish iterating, what happens to that `using`?  Answer: The `finally` portion of the `using` never gets invoked thereby never calling `Dispose` on the `TextReader` and never closing the open file.  Similarly, imagine that the `using` were replaced with `lock(something)`.  The `finally` portion of the `lock` will never be invoked never releasing the lock on the object.

**Lesson**: Always avoid using `try..finally` and it's derivatives in an iterator block.

Comment: Do you avoid ever implementing IDisposable in other types, too? Yes, callers who aren't careful will end up leaking resources - but that's the case everywhere. I wouldn't use try/finally in an iterator block for *security* purposes, but for simple resource release I'd say it's okay. Things like line readers are *really* handy.

Comment: The question asked for corner cases regarding iterators/yield.  I'd say that, yes, leaking resources and the possibility of having odd concurrency issues are interesting corner cases and possible gotchas.  I just said to avoid using try..finally in iterators, not to never use it. I guess it really boils down to the fact that the code that is after any given yield may not ever get executed leading to unintended behavior.

Comment: Indeed, locks in iterators are pure evil. Locks should be held for as little time as possible (for high performance if there is contention) and the code that runs while the lock is taken should be well-known by the author of the lock (to avoid deadlocks).  Both best practices are easily violated when the lock is in an iterator. Arbitrary time can pass and arbitrary code can run while in the lock.